# How do i root Android x86_64?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rooting, scripts

I installed android x86_64 and now I want to root it but all the root scripts are for 32-bit versions of Android.

I am using console os lollipop that is not rooted.

What are my options?

Thanks

Comment: Exactly which Android version are you using? I don't see any 5.0 based image here: http://www.android-x86.org/download

Comment: Additionally, on which device?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an x86_64 build from http://www.android-x86.org/download, such as android-x86_64-5.1-rc1.img, it is already rooted.  There's no need to run a root script.

If that's not where you're getting your image from, please update your answer to add that important detail.